# Css lose efficacy in safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

I have an HTML5 program which functions properly on Android but does not with iOS devices. The paragraphs bunch together at the top of the screen.

Perhaps the CSS does not work the same on iOS devices. Thank you.

**iOS device Screenshot:**

[image: iOS device Screenshot]

**Android device Screenshot:**

[image: Android device Screenshot]

Comment: .p1_title_1{top: 52vh;}
.p1_title_2{top: 56vh;}
.p1_title_3{top: 60vh;}
.p1_title_4{top: 64vh;}
.p1_title_5{top: 68vh;}
.p1_title_6{top: 72vh;}here's my code.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your code and any error messages!

Comment: I've submitted an edit request on your question so that other users can easily understand your problem. Good luck!

Comment: What Android and iOS devices are you using? What browsers are you using on each device?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you very much@MatthewCliatt,Thank you for your description that others could easily know my problems.I use chrome in android and safari in iphone.In my test,iphone6,iphone5s,iphone5,ipad mini have the same problem that the paragraphs bunch together at the top of the screen.today later I have work out the problems.Because I use animation and I put the keyframes code in the middle of the css.And I found after the keyframes ,all the css behind lose effect.So I put the keyframes in the bottom of all the css.And the problem disappear.Though I don't know why.